# Best way to construct a cache key whose uniqueness is defined by 6 properties

Tags: caching, redis

Currently I am tasked to fix cache for an ecommerce like system whose prices depend on many factors. The cache backend is redis. For a given product the factors that influence the price are:

sku

channel

sub channel

plan

date

Currently the cache is structured like this in redis:

```
product1_channel1_subchannel1:  {sku_1:  {plan1: {2019-03-18: 2000}}}
```

The API caters to requests for multiple products, skus and all the factors above . So they decided to query all the data on a product_channel_subchannel level and filter the data in the app which is very slow. Also they have decided that, on a cache miss they will construct the cache for all skus for 90 days of data. This way only one request will face the wrath while the others gets benefited from it (only the catch is now we are busting cache more often which is also dragging the system down)

The downside of going with all these factors included in the keys is there will be too many keys. To ball park there are 400 products each made up of 20 skus with 20 channels, 200 subchannels 3 types of plans and 400 days of pricing. To avoid these many keys at some place we must group the data.

The system is currently receives about 10 rps and the has to respond within 100ms.

Question is:

Is the above cache structure fine? Or how do we go about flattening this structure?

How are caches stored in pricing systems in general. I feel like this a very trivial task nonetheless I find it very hard to justify my approaches

Is it okay to sacrifice one request to warm cache for bulk of the data? Or is it better to have a cache warming strategy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any sort of caching strategy will be an exercise in trade-offs. And the precise trade-offs you need to make will be dependent upon complex domain logic that you can't predict until you try it out.

What this means is that whatever you implement should be based on data and should be flexible enough to change over time as the business changes. In particular the answer to these questions:

> Is it okay to sacrifice one request to warm cache for bulk of the data? Or is it better to have a cache warming strategy?

depend on how the data will be queried by your users and how long a cache miss will take. If queries tend to be clustered around certain skus, or certain dates in a predictable manner, then you should use that information to help guide cache hits and misses.

There is no way I, or anyone else, can give you a correct answer without doing proper experimentation, but we can give you some guidelines.

Here are some best practices that I would recommend when using redis for caching:

1. If the bottleneck is sending data from redis to the api, then consider using lua scripts to do the simple processing before any data leaves redis. But, be careful that you don't make the scripts too complex since a long-running lua script can block all other parts of redis
2. It looks like you are using simple get/set keys to store your data. Consider using something more complex:

   a. use sorted sets (zsets) if you want to have better access to data by date (use the date as the score).
   b. use hash sets to get more fine-grained access to skus
3. Based on your question, it looks like you will have about 1.6M keys. This is not a huge amount, but you need to make sure that redis has enough memory to store everything in ram without swapping anything to disk. This is something that we had to learn the hard way. If you are running your redis instance on linux, you must set the system's swappiness to 0, to ensure swap is never used.

But, most importantly, you need to experiment with everything until you find a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. I will look into hash sets. We use elasticache. But thanks again for the heads up on swappiness. I guess I will try to experiment but will flatten every key except dates. 
Is there any resources/open source code bases that you can point me through on how the cache architecture of proven/popular systems are structured?

Comment: I don't have anything I can really point you to. Most of our work in this area has been trial and error. I'd take a good look at this part of the redis docs, though. https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#use-hashes-when-possible